# Button Click not working on Android Studio (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

My .kt file

```
class meatsupreme : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_meatsupreme)
        val orderButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.submitButton)

        orderButton.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("ButtonClicked", "Order button clicked")

            // Log a message to verify the button click event
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a pizza size", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }


}
```

and my button

```
    <Button

        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.878"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/meaticon"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/orderbutton"/>
```

When i press log only EGL_emulation shows up
Any help would be wonderful
Tried to toast but button click not working

Comment: Post the complete xml `activity_meatsupreme`

Comment: Are you sure R.id.submitButton inside R.layout.activity_meatsupreme?

Comment: Try to rename the button id in both places

Comment: Please, consider posting your full activity_meatsupreme.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try with viewBinding to ensure that you are pointing to the correct layout and button.

With viewBinding, you won't have to find the view by it's ID which might select the target view needed and can debug better what's the issue.

Also, please check if you have any overlay view over the Button in the xml which is set to clickable=true, focusable=true.

For viewBinding you can refer the android documentation, it's pretty simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

in above activity on setOnClickListener you wrote only toast and log  , if you want perform any action you can write code

in top means below class you have to declaree like this
val orderButton:Button
then you can directly use the orderButton on onCreatr view
for intent
orderButton.setOnClickListener {
val intent = Intent(applicationContext,AnotherActivity::Class.java)
startIntent(intent)
}

and for any other operations you have to write the specific operation